# Web request from inside PHP slower then browser

Tags: php

I have a web request from 1 server to another that is taking 1 second. The same request in my browser takes almost no time. I have looked through the various similar questions and tried all the offered suggestions I could find including

- use curl instead of file_get_contents
- embed your own close connection header in the file_get_contents
- use google as the domain to speedup domain lookup
- use a header on the target server to avoid keep alive

None of these has made any impact on the time. Here are the ways I tried this:

```
$timeBefore = microtime(true);


//Only one of these active at a time
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$output = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);

//Or
$context=stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>"Host: www.google.com\r\n")));
$output = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

//Or
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

$timeAfter = microtime(true);
```

and then log to a file `$timeAfter - $timeBefore`. I always get around 1.04202604294 as the result and the client app that uses this actually sees the 1 second delay.

As a side note in case it is relevant, the 2 servers here are talking in the following manner A to B, during B's answer to A it sends this URL back to A, then takes all that and sends its original response back to A. So there is a connection back to the source during the connection from the source.

Here is the debug output from curl_getinfo

```
content_type => text/html,
http_code => 200,
header_size => 219,
request_size => 479,
filetime => -1,
ssl_verify_result => 0,
redirect_count => 0,
total_time => 1.04360199999999991860022419132292270660400390625,
namelookup_time => 0.0001579999999999999915796522476085783637245185673236846923828125,
connect_time => 0.0007219999999999999855393451042573360609821975231170654296875,
pretransfer_time => 0.000772000000000000008264222639553508997778408229351043701171875,
size_upload => 0,
size_download => 1,
speed_download => 0,
speed_upload => 0,
download_content_length => -1,
upload_content_length => -1,
starttransfer_time => 1.0435689999999999688640173189924098551273345947265625,
redirect_time => 0,
redirect_url =>
```

This command is being sent from 2 servers on the same hosting service to each other, and they are both not under load and its a high quality hosting site(liquid web dedicated server). The response and url are both very small

Comment: Have a look at `curl_getinfo`, which should indicate how long each phase of the lookup took e.g. how long did it take to resolve the name from DNS, etc. This will show you what area needs optimisation.

Comment: I have added the output from that in the above.

Comment: Hmm, the `starttransfer_time` is the bulk of the time - do you get similar slow times for other servers? Where is your server and the target server located, and how far apart are they?

Comment: They should be in the same physical location. Nothing else is slow these servers process lots of requests.

Comment: Ah, if the two servers are in the same datacentre, talk to your hosting provider to help debugging the source of the delay. Perhaps they can use some network tracing tools to help find out what is causing it?

Comment: So i puttyed into the server and pinged the other server and the response times were less then 1 millisecond so I feel like it must be something in the php

Comment: It's probably not possible for readers to say. Talk to your hosting provider.

Comment: I did contact them. They said they cannot really solve php related problems as it is not a general server problem. In the end I think I will just try to re-architect it to not need the back and forth as the other legs of the trip are just fine.

Comment: It depends how you ask (they are right that PHP problems are out of their scope, but this may not be a PHP problem). Have you tried a `wget` or `curl` from the console? A `ping` is not a fair comparison. If you get a slow fetch from the console, you have a networking issue they can (or should) help you with.

Answer (score 2):

This is something almost impossible to diagnose without running the exact same code and connecting to the same site in our browsers. But in general, your browser is going to do more to negotiate a fast connection with the server than CURL. This includes supporting HTTP/2 & gzip, both of which make data transfer faster from end to end.

Comment: of note the payload in this request is fairly small and a ping between the 2 machines is <1 ms so I feel like there is something more going on then optimization to get the speed up to 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that it takes time to contact another page/server.
What you can do is to limit the number of connections it does by caching the data for x minutes. (if possible)

I cache my data to a txt file with put_file_contents() and then use filemtime() to see how old the file is.
This way you only need to read from your local txt file with file_get_contents() to get the data.

This will speed it up, but it also means you may display "dated" data.

Comment: This is actually a command that is being given and not a webpage showing so thats not an option.